# R ggplot boxplot Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (100): x, y

Tags: r, ggplot2, error-handling, boxplot

I am trying to create a boxplot with the data frame `grades_software`, `software` as a discrete variable X (R/SPSS) and `grades` as a continuous variable Y.

I used the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(grades_software, aes(software, grades_software$final_score)) + 
geom_boxplot(fill = fill, colour = line) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "final_score",
                     breaks = seq(0, 175, 25),
                     limits=c(0, 175)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "software") +
  ggtitle("Distribution of Final Course Scores by Software Used")
```

However, I get the error stated above:

> Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (100): x, y

I also don't know what's the function of putting `breaks = seq` and `limits` in the code.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) on how to make a great R reproducible example.

Comment: Try replacing `aes(software, grades_software$final_score))` with `aes(software, final_score))`. Reason because the dataframe is already specified, we only need to specify the column names within `aes`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify `$` for the columns with ggplot.

Try

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(grades_software, aes(software, final_score)) + 
geom_boxplot(fill = fill, colour = line) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "final_score",
                     breaks = seq(0, 175, 25),
                     limits=c(0, 175)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "software") +
  ggtitle("Distribution of Final Course Scores by Software Used")
```

With `breaks` you control the gridlines of the graph. `Seq` creates a sequence of gridlines `seq(from, to, by)`. In you example... set gridlines from 0 to 175 every 25. `Limits`, om the other hand, is a numeric vector of length two providing limits of the scale. In your case, from 0 to 175.